# Flink 1.9 : Standalone Cluster : Failed to transfer file from TaskExecutor id : `AskTimeoutException`

Tags: java, timeout, akka, apache-flink

**Background**

Trying to create Apache Flink Standalone cluster.

*Environment :* AWS
*Job Manager :* **1**
*Task Manager :* **2**
*Config :*

```
FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR                       :   /usr/local/flink-1.9.1/plugins
io.tmp.dirs                             :   /tmp/flink
jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy  :   region
jobmanager.heap.size                    :   1024m
jobmanager.rpc.address                  :   job manager ip
jobmanager.rpc.port                     :   6123
jobstore.cache-size                     :   52428800
jobstore.expiration-time                :   3600
parallelism.default                     :   4
slot.idle.timeout                       :   50000
slot.request.timeout                    :   300000
task.cancellation.interval              :   30000
task.cancellation.timeout               :   180000
task.cancellation.timers.timeout        :   7500
taskmanager.exit-on-fatal-akka-error    :   false
taskmanager.heap.size                   :   1024m
taskmanager.network.bind-policy         :   "ip"
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots           :   2
taskmanager.registration.initial-backoff:   500ms
taskmanager.registration.timeout        :   5min
taskmanager.rpc.port                    :   50100-50200
web.tmpdir                              :   /tmp/flink-web-74cce811-17c0-411e-9d11-6d91edd2e9b0
```

*Instance Type :* **t2 medium (2 CPUs 4 GB Memory)**
*Security Group ports opened :* **6123, 8081, 50100 - 50200**

*OS :* **CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**

*Java :*

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

- Cluster is up and running properly

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - http://ip:8081 was granted leadership with leaderSessionID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Web frontend listening at http:/ip:8081.
org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager at akka://flink/user/resourcemanager .
org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher at akka://flink/user/dispatcher .
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@ip:6123/user/resourcemanager was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000000000000000000000000000
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl  - Starting the SlotManager.
org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Dispatcher akka.tcp://flink@ip:6123/user/dispatcher was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Recovering all persisted jobs.
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID f2c7f664378b40ce44463713ae98e1c4 (akka.tcp://flink@TaskManager1Ip:38566/user/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 354a785f637751fb3b034618a47480ed (akka.tcp://flink@TaskManager2Ip:34400/user/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
```

- UI shows all the cluster details
  [image]

[image]

**Problem**

The task submission does not work

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/resourcemanager#-1545644127]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn'
t send a reply.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:871)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:74)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:644)
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/resourcemanager#-1545644127]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648)
        ... 9 more
2020-02-04 23:25:16,125 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.taskmanager.TaskManagerLogFileHandler  - Unhandled exception.
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/resourcemanager#-1545644127]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648)
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can somebody  throw some light on this ? Is it problem related to ports / firewall or some setting is messed up ?

Comment: For such a small cluster, ask timeout usually means that you Flink fails to connect to external systems during job creation. For example, the port of some service is wrong or blocked by firewall.

Comment: Task manager logs show failed attempts to connect to the metrics server on ports 39493/34094, maybe this delayed the heartbeat response

Comment: I added entire port range from 0-65535. That did the trick. But is there any way to configure or control this range ? I tried configuring `taskmanager.rpc.port : 50100- 50200' but it did not help. Is there any other parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with security group port permissions. When opened entire range from `0 - 65565`, everything started working. Still this is not good enough for production system so eventually for Job workers in the `flink-conf.yaml`  config file, the key `taskmanager.data.port` was assigned a particular port and that did the trick. This way the task managers could be configured to listen to a particular port within the range.

Comment: Hi Did you get the solution?

Comment: Yes. it is mentioned in the answer above. Setting `taskmanager.data.port`

Comment: I am running my flink cluster on Kubernetes and there the port are assigned automatically.Also, I di tried to assign it a particular port but was getting the same error and couldn't control the ask time out setting.